# How to use an extension function in a companion object

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods

Is it possible to define and use an extension function in a class' companion object?

In this example `removePadding()` is the extension function being used in `Point.parse()`.

```
data class Point(private var x: Int, private var y: Int) {
    companion object {
        fun parse(text: String?) = text?.removePadding()
            ?.let { "(\\d+),(\\d+)".toRegex().find(it) }
            ?.mapNotNull { it.toIntOrNull() }
            ?.let { Point(it[0], it[1]) }

        // define removePadding() here?
    }

    // define removePadding() here?
}
```

The extension function `removePadding()` may look like:

```
fun String.removePadding() = this.replace("\\s+".toRegex(), "")
```

And the `parse` function may be called as:

```
val one = Point.parse("1, 7")
```

If it's possible, how? If it's not, why not?

Comment: Since it should be an extension function of `String`, it shouldn't be inside a `data class` but outside the scope. I also think the `replace("\\s#")` won't compile, you haven't provided a replacement `String` for the arbitrary amount of whitespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could basically place the extension in any of those places, declaring it normally:

```
private fun String.removePadding() = this.replace("\\s+".toRegex(), "")
```

<sup>The `private` modifier limits the visibility to the companion object or the `data` class, depending on where you place it. Usually, one should prefer the narrowest possible visibility scope for a declaration.</sup>

And another option is to declare the extension function locally in the `parse` function (note that it doesn't have the visibility modifier this time):

```
data class Point(private var x: Int, private var y: Int) {
    companion object {
        fun parse(text: String?): Point? {
            fun String.removePadding() = this.replace("\\s+".toRegex(), "")

            return text?.removePadding()
                ?.let { "(\\d+),(\\d+)".toRegex().find(it) }
                ?.groupValues?.map { it.toIntOrNull() ?: return null }
                ?.let { (x, y) -> Point(x, y) }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need the function as a helper for `parse`, you should declare it next to it.

```
companion object {
    private fun String.removeWhitespace() = replace("\\s+".toRegex(), "")

    fun parse(text: String?): Point? {
        ...
```